# Как определить радиус круга поиска в "API поиск по организациям"

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Не могу понять , как седлать запрос , чтобы от определенный точки (обозначенной координатами) был поиск мест (по методу text) в определенном круговом радиусе. Я смотрел на 2 метода spn и bbox, но там требуются какие-то координаты.. Я совсем не понял, как работать с выбранной областью(

Answer (score 1):

Никакого радиуса в API ППО Яндекса и нет.
Оба варианта, и spn и bbox задают прямоугольную рамку, ограничивающую зону поиска.

Параметром bbox вы прямо задаёте координаты противоположных углов такой рамки. Их можно скопировать, например, на Яндекс.Карте. Этот вариант больше подходит для единичных, ручных запросов к ППО.

В параметре spn передается расстояние (в градусах) от центра области поиска (ll) до её краев. Такой метод больше подходит для автоматических запросов по разным координатам центра и размерам поиска. Если вам нужно установить рамку на нужном расстоянии от центра поиска, то необходимо пересчитать километры в градусы. Информацию или калькуляторы для подобных вычислений есть в сети. Но если кратко, то:

- длина одного градуса по широте (север — юг) всегда равна примерно 111 км ;
- длина одного градуса по долготе (запад — восток) вычисляется: длина дуги экватора в 1° (111,3 км) * косинус угла, соответствующего географической широте искомой параллели;
  Например, длина одного градуса долготы на широте Москвы будет:
  cos 55.753215° * 111.3 км = 0,5628 * 111.3 км = 62.6 км
  Соответственно, длина километра в градусах в Москве:
- по широте: 1 / 111 = 0.009°
- по долготе: 1 / 62.6 = 0.016°

Порядок задания координат - долгота, широта. Задаются в градусах, представленных в виде десятичной дроби.